# Python-Scripting in ArcGIS: Point as Input?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, point

Is there any possibility to add a Point-Feature as an input parameter in a ArcPy-/ArcGIS-Python-script? If I choose "Point" as datatype in the parameter list, I get 2 input-fields for a X- and a Y-coordinate. 
What I want is something like a button to get a crossfade cursor for selecting "on-click" a coordinate in the map. 
Is there anything like this?

Comment: I would look into using a Feature Set.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your tool to interact with the map, you need to write a python add-in. To retrieve the X and Y coords of the point you click, use the `x` and `y` values of the `onMouseUpMap()` or `onMouseDownMap()` function of the [Tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Tool/014p00000027000000/) add-in class.

You have a nice example of code that corresponds to this in this article: [HowTo:  Capture map coordinates with a mouse click using Python](http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/40730).

And the help section about Python add-ins is [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/tool/014p0000001q000000/).

Comment: A Python AddIn is a good option but a regular tool authored using either ModelBuilder or Python using a Feature Set parameter can also be used.